# Given start strings, find simplest DAG that constructs target strings by concatenation

Tags: algorithms, graphs, strings, dag

Say we have a number of start strings (green) and a number of target strings (red). Two strings can always be concatenated to a new string which can then be arbitrarily often reused (two arrows in, (1,∞) arrows out). A string can also be concatenated with itself.

[image: String concatenation DAG]

Is there an algorithm that can tell if this is the DAG that has the least number of nodes?

Is there an algorithm that gives *a* DAG that constructs the strings?

Is there an algorithm that gives *the least complex (by number of nodes)* DAG?

Does this problem have a name?

It seems that this is related to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem (but it is not a minimal spanning tree, because the paths could be disjoint).

Someone pointed me to the addition sequence problem, which seems equivalent and is NP-complete: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0210047

Comment: In your example the starting strings form a disjoint alphabet. Is this always the case, or could the starting strings share characters (e.g. $BAB$ and $ABA$), or even share common prefix/suffixes (e.g. $AC$ and $ABA$)?

Comment: @orlp The starting strings have no restrictions